# unbound method __init__() must be called with LocaleRegexProvider instance as first argument (got RegexURLPattern instance instead)

Tags: python, django

I'm working on [a patch for django-localeurl](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-localeurl/pull-request/6/changes-for-issue-23) and I've bumped into a problem that puzzles me. To test the functionality added by my patch, I've added tests that triggers this error when I run them against Django trunk (no problem with older releases):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/al/dev/projects/django-localeurl/localeurl/tests/tests.py", line 498, in test_change_locale_check_session_disabled
    self.client.post('/change/', data={'locale': 'de', 'next': '/foo'})
  File "/home/al/dev/projects/django-localeurl/.tox/py26-trunk/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 449, in post
    response = super(Client, self).post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "/home/al/dev/projects/django-localeurl/.tox/py26-trunk/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 262, in post
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/home/al/dev/projects/django-localeurl/.tox/py26-trunk/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 381, in request
    response = self.handler(environ)
  File "/home/al/dev/projects/django-localeurl/.tox/py26-trunk/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 84, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/al/dev/projects/django-localeurl/.tox/py26-trunk/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/al/dev/projects/django-localeurl/.tox/py26-trunk/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 224, in handle_uncaught_exception
    if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
  File "/home/al/dev/projects/django-localeurl/.tox/py26-trunk/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 323, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/al/dev/projects/django-localeurl/.tox/py26-trunk/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/al/dev/projects/django-localeurl/localeurl/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    url(r'^change/', change_locale, name='localeurl_change_locale'),
  File "/home/al/dev/projects/django-localeurl/.tox/py26-trunk/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 60, in url
    return RegexURLPattern(regex, view, kwargs, name)
  File "/home/al/dev/projects/django-localeurl/.tox/py26-trunk/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 172, in __init__
    LocaleRegexProvider.__init__(self, regex)
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with LocaleRegexProvider instance as first argument (got RegexURLPattern instance instead)
```

But When I read [the code that triggers this exception](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py?rev=17251#L172), I can't see how this can happen. In order to understand the situation I added those print statements above the line where the base `__init__` is called:

```
print
print "self.__class__:", self.__class__
print "self.__class__.__bases__:", self.__class__.__bases__
print "isinstance(self, LocaleRegexProvider):", isinstance(self, LocaleRegexProvider)
print
LocaleRegexProvider.__init__(self, regex)
```

In some cases this gives me the expected output:

```
self.__class__: <class 'django.core.urlresolvers.RegexURLPattern'>
self.__class__.__bases__: (<class 'django.core.urlresolvers.LocaleRegexProvider'>,)
isinstance(self, LocaleRegexProvider): True
```

But in some cases it gives me this strange result:

```
self.__class__: <class 'django.core.urlresolvers.RegexURLPattern'>
self.__class__.__bases__: (<class 'django.core.urlresolvers.LocaleRegexProvider'>,)
isinstance(self, LocaleRegexProvider): False
```

Initially I thought some other part of Django might be dynamically changing the base class of the `RegexURLPattern` instance (here referred as `self`), which causes an exception to be raised when calling `LocaleRegexProvider.__init__`. My supposition seems to be confirmed by the result of `isinstance` but printing out the `__bases__` contradict this. I thought that if `LocaleRegexProvider` is in the list of base classes, `isinstance` should always return `True`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in [reload()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) function, which you use in your tests to reload the url settings. According to documentation:

> As with all other objects in Python the old
>   objects are only reclaimed after their reference counts drop to zero.
>   The names in the module namespace are updated to point to any new or
>   changed objects. Other references to the old objects (such as names
>   external to the module) are not rebound to refer to the new objects
>   and must be updated in each namespace where they occur if that is
>   desired.

So you're reloading the `urlresolvers` module, but this is not side-effect free. Objects from old `urlresolvers` are not destroyed by `reload`. At some point you have in the memory instances of two copies of `RegexURLPattern` class. These are different classes (class objects) with exactly the same name and location in the code. That causes errors which you are seeing, when object of the new `RegexURLPattern` class is not an instance of the old `RegexURLPattern` object, and it's base class constructor cannot be called.